# 5G: How to Integrate or Implement the 3GPP NWDAF?

Tags: 5g, nfv

I set up a [Free5GC with EURANSIM](https://www.free5gc.org/installations/stage-3/) emulator. As specified in the test cases, the setup is functioning as intended.

Currently, I'm attempting to integrate the 5G 3GPP NWDAF (Network Data Analytics Function). I've read the 3GPP TS 23.288 and other related TSs. Moreover, I looked through [GitHub repositories](https://github.com/search?p=1&q=nwdaf&type=Repositories) for implementations of the NWDAF. But, there are no readme files or documentations that describe how to deploy or integrate these repos with my emulator setup.

I'm currently looking for a base from which I may develop or implement my own NWDAF in accordance with 3GPP guidelines.

I'd be grateful for any guidance or advise.

**UPDATE**:

Basically, I need help with:

**How can I develop, create, design or build ANY network function, including any associated interfaces and services, that is stated in the 3GPP and O-RAN technical specifications into practical implementations?**

Comment: I'm afraid, requests for resources are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. But perhaps someone could provide you with a direct answer.

Comment: @Zac67: I appreciate your response. Finding resources like reading materials or man pages is not as much of a concern for me as finding a starting point for how to develop a service based on a standard, of which there is now none. As a guide to developing similar functions or services, I'm confident that this will be useful for many more people. But I apologize for not being on-topic per-se.

Comment: I'm sorry but programming is *really* off topic here and your question is (still) far too broad. If you change your question appropriately we can reopen it.

Comment: @Zac67 : I am assuming that this website is meant to help members find the right answer and guidance to their questions related to networking; including telecom networks. Hence my post. I'm also assuming you are the one who labelled the question as off-topic. It would be understandable if you think that the post is too generic. But I failed to see how you made it about programming!! If I were you and failed to relate the question to my own knowledge and expertise, I would still leave it for others to help answer it or comment. Anyway, I will try to rephrase it more concisely.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about applications and host/server/VM configurations are off-topic here. Also, remember that to be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support. Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

Comment: @RonMaupin : Thank you. After all, we are all here to learn from each other.

Comment: @Zac67 : Thank you too